# Window-shadow causes weird bugs in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bug, text-editor, web-browser

I'm coding a website, just with a text editor and my browser. I use Sublime Text 3 and Google Chrome. When I hover my text editor over my browser, the background color of my site gets a bit darker in the area's of the shadows of the text editor. I don't really know how to explain this so have a look at this pic:

I have this on a mac of course, but when I make a screenshot the bug disappears. (Not my own pic)

[image: "Weird"]

I have this kind of lag when i'm dragging, but instead of window copies, the shadow lags and instead of shadows it's like a dark shade.

It's really hard to explain without pictures!

It's kinda buggin me because with this I can't really look at my website with ease.

I hope anyone has a solution or at least a similar problem!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually have this same problem and thought I was going crazy, or my graphics card was getting ready to die. Now that I think about it, it only happens when Chrome is in the background and there is some other window on top of it. It started not long ago, maybe around January?

Comment: @tubedogg Yes it happened to me since January too. Maybe it's because of a software update?

Comment: I recommend doing lots of testing and reporting it on the [Chromium issues list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list), where someone will probably be able to help troubleshoot and fix the bug.

Comment: Thank you, haven't seen that service before, thanks for the tip :D